# Stopping a while loop when a condition is met in a userinput list

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

Please I'm trying to create a register that appends to a list the user input, breaks and returns to the prompt for user to "input data" but only stops when a string "done" is inputed.

```
userinput = input("Please Input price: ")
price = [userinput]

    while True:
       if price.append(userinput) is True:
        print(price)
       if price.append("done") is True:
        break

    print(price)
```

Comment: Do you know how python indentation works?

Comment: You have numerous problems. The indentation is wrong. You only ever take input once. The result of appending to a list is always `None`, never `True`. You nowhere attempt to check if the input is equal to `"done"`, adding that string to the list instead is totally backwards. I'd strongly recommend you run through some basic tutorials and think more carefully about the logic you're trying to implement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
userinput = input("Please Input price: ")
price = []

while userinput != "done":
    price.append(userinput)
    print(price)  # This appears to serve as debugging only, you will see the whole list as it is grown
    userinput = input("Please Input price: ")

print(price)
```